# Used 'drawnow', but cannot use the the menubar before reaching end of the script

Tags: matlab

I made `.m` file something like this to create unlimited number of figures:

```
while 1
   x = 1:10
   y = cos(x)
   figure
   plot(x,y)
   drawnow
end
```

After I get figure, I cannot use the menubar on the figure ( ex. cannot save the file, plot not automatically resize when I manually change the figure size) until I pause the app.

Comment: That is normal behavior. Add short `pause` statements to your loop if you want the UI to remain interactive.

Comment: If I add pause() statement after drawnow, .m file stops running. Are there any other way to use the menu bar while running m file?

Comment: Add a short pause, not an indefinite one. `pause(0.1)` or something like that.

Comment: still cannot use the toolbar while running after adding pause(0.1) statement

Comment: What is the question here?